# Command after json loop in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, loops

I have a problem with jquery,
When the page loads I call a json file and and loop over its items. But I cannot attache any event listeners to the input button added.

I want to do for example an alert message..

I think I connot `select` the input button by jquery

```
    $.getJSON("data.json", function(json) {
    var html = "";
      json['products'].forEach(function(val){
        var location = '"?id='+val.id+'"';
        html += "<div class='item'>"
        html += "<div class='item-header'>";
        html += "<h3>" + val.item_name + "</h3></div>";
        html += "<div class='item-img'>";
        html += "<img src='http://www.safensound.com.my/public/images/no_product_img.jpg' title=" + val.item_name + "></img></div>"
        html += "<div class='item-footer'>";
        html += "<p>Country: " + val.country_of_origin + "</p>";
        html += "<p>Price: " + val.price + " $</p>";
        html += "<input type='button' data-id='"+val.id+"' class='btn btn-success' value='Add to cart'></input>";
        html += "</div></div>";
      });

    $(".items").html(html);
  });
```

and this is the onclick command:

```
$("item-footer>input[type='button']").on("click", function(){
    alert("Hi");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For dynamically created elements, you need to have at least one static element which is a parent of the others :

```
$("#SOME_STATIC_PARENT").on("click",".item-footer>input[type='button']", function(){
    alert("Hi");
});
```

In your example, `.items` might be good, so :

```
$(".items").on("click",".item-footer>input[type='button']", function(){
    alert("Hi");
});
```

Comment: What is the `#SOME_STATIC_PARENT`?

Comment: An element that is created within the html page, without javascript (static), such as body or perhaps the container div of your page.